# Create file inside a Folder on Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am very new to javascript and automating in google. I am trying to create a doc called Promo Text inside a folder I have just created.

I am able to create 2 sub folders inside the newFolder as well as return the URL to the sheet but, although the Google Apps Script editor gives the option of .createFile, I get the error of

> Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.Folder.createFile. (line 23, file "Code")

Line 23 is
`` const promoText = newFolder.createFile(`${row[1]} Promo Text`,) ``

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Cheers.

```
function createReleaseFolder() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Schedule');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
    rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[18]) return;
    if (row[0] === 'DJ'){
  
    const releasesFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1OKZEdZxu8BCgJFv4H7pcRGMNjc")
    const newFolder = releasesFolder.createFolder(`${row[1]} ${row[2]} - ${row[3]}`,)
    const audioMasters = newFolder.createFolder("Audio Masters")
    const assets = newFolder.createFolder("Assets")
    const promoText = newFolder.createFile(`${row[1]} Promo Text`,)
    
    const url = newFolder.getUrl();
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 19).setValue(url)
    }

    })}
```

Comment: where is line 23 on your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function lfunko() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Schedule');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const releasesFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1OKZEdZxu8BCgJFv4H7pcRGMNjc")
  rows.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[18]) return;
    if (row[0] === 'DJ') {
      let newFolder = releasesFolder.createFolder(`${row[1]} ${row[2]} - ${row[3]}`);
      newFolder.createFolder("Audio Masters");
      newFolder.createFolder("Assets");
      newFolder.createFile(`${row[1]} Promo Text`,"This is the content");//last change
      sheet.getRange(index + 1, 19).setValue(newFolder.getUrl());
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper. Same error on the `newFolder.createFile(`${row[1]} Promo Text`);` line unfortunately.

Comment: What are row values?

Comment: They're pulling from the sheet. If I fix the value to `newFolder.createFile("Promo Text")` its the same error. Sorry if thats not what you asked, Im completely new to this. Cheers.

Comment: It works now for me.  You needed to add some content for the file.  You had a name but no content

Comment: Ah, fantastic, thanks. I assumed you could leave the content blank. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably could have gone with `, nul` but I didn't try it.